# Не могу закрыть соединение С БД в python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3

Есть скрипт, основная его часть это:

```
try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('Posts.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
...
except:
...
except:

finally:
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

Дело в том, что у меня в коде после открытия соединения и курсора могут быть сгенерированы ошибки, и я хочу закрывать соединение независимо от того, произошли ошибки или нет.

Как это лучше оформить? В каждом except у меня после принта ошибки стоит raise `SystemExit`. Если я напишу в finally:

```
cur.close()
con.close()
```

то до их выполнения дело может и не дойти? Да и интерпретатор выводит ошибку `NameError: name 'cur' is not defined`

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, полностью код с местом где вы делаете `raise SystemExit`
Есть ощущение, что вы неверно используете `try \ except`

Comment: Другой мой проект, но построен он по аналогичной схеме:https://github.com/rsherstnev/keywordsfounder/blob/master/keywordsfounder.py

Comment: Если красиво, то это использовать with и closing из contextlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка `NameError: name 'cur' is not defined` происходит при обращении к переменной, что не была инициализирована (считай, создана), поэтому заранее создаете их, а в `finally` проверяете, что у них есть значения:

```
con = None
cur = None

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('Posts.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
...
except:
...
except:

finally:
    if cur is not None:
        cur.close()

    if con is not None:
        con.close()
```

Comment: with не закроет коннект при таком использовании. Так вы открываете соединение и стартуете транзакцию, которая в конце просто будет commit(), а соединение останется открытым.

Comment: @vitidev, спасибо за замечание, вы правы

Comment: @NordeN, в ответе было что `with` вызывает `close`, но это была ошибка -- этот оператор автоматически вызывает коммит или откат изменений (в случае ошибок): https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager `"Connection objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions."`